# How to check discard custom attribute of method?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

There is a function call:

```
(_, var surname) = Foo();
```

and the function:

```
(string Name, string Surname) Foo() 
{
    // Does the 'Name' attribute have discard symbol?
    ....
}
```

Is it possible to know it from runtime?

Comment: there isn't a way to know if a return value is used or not - you could always return a class or other data structure that detects if a property has been read or not

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This seems like an X/Y problem.

Comment: @madreflection, I want to optimize a function body. I'm sure compiler can pass such info when calls method.

Comment: If you need to choose an optimal path, take a parameter indicating whether the caller needs the output that requires the less optimal path.

Answer (score 2):

C# 7 have underscore character _ called discards to create dummy variables. Discards are equal to unassigned variables. The purpose of this feature is to use this variable when you want to intentionally skip the value by not creating a variable explicitly.

In this example, you just calling the Foo method but as a return value, you intentionally don't need the Name and just use _ to discard it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    (_, var surname) = Foo();

    Console.WriteLine(surname);
}
static (string Name, string Surname) Foo()
{
    return ("Uncle", "Bob");
}
```

Now lets see an ideal situation to use discards variable:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse("04/16/2022", out _))  
{  
     Console.WriteLine("Date is valid");  
}  
else  
{  
    Console.WriteLine("Date is not valid");  
}
```

But if you don't use _ then you should consider the scenario as per below:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse("04/16/2022", out var result))  
{  
    Console.WriteLine("Date is valid");  
}  
else  
{  
    Console.WriteLine("Date is not valid");  
}
```

For more information about _ you can check [Discards - C# Fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards)

Comment: Consider using `DateTime.TryParse("04/16/2022", out var result)` in the second example because it avoids definite assignment and scoping issues.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Good point, although the purpose of this snippet was to demonstrate _ in c# yet I applied the change as per your review.